# Why Bootstrap Progressbar doesn't work on IE 11

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap, internet-explorer-11, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to bring in the progress bar dynamically but it doesn't work for me on IE 11.

```
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" role="progressbar"    
     aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%;"
     ng-style="{width: (percentageCompletionInitialQues)+'%'}"></div>
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: what version of angular and ui bootstrap are you using ? did your code work on IE 10 and 9 ?

Comment: Hi @svarog am using (Angularjs 1.4.7). I didn't worked on IE9 and 10. Now am working with IE11.